# Triangular-wave to sinewave converter with symmetrical circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, homework

I don't think I have a solid approach when analyzing complex circuits like these. I hope some of you can give me general directions and help me tackle this one.

[image]

Given that the diodes are ideal and \$V_s(t)\$ is a triangular waveform generator, I am asked to:

1. Derive the analytic expression of the transcharacteristic \$V_o \; = \; f(V_s)\$ and draw it.
2. Recognize eventual properties and characteristics of the circuit.

Whenever I analyze circuits with diodes I always start by supposing that all of them and the AC generator are off to check their actual bias. I also try to redraw the circuit to simplify it a bit and maybe find familiar configurations. No luck with this one.

I started with something like this:

[image] and ended up with this: [image]

I won't bother you with my first try, I ended up failing to find a clean solution so I asked my professor about it. He didn't have much time and the only thing he managed to tell me was that all the time I wasted on my calculations could have been saved if only I had noticed that this was a symmetric circuit and then he showed me the graph of the transcharacteristic which was, in fact, symmetric to the \$V_o = V_s\$ line.

I went back at it again and this is how I proceeded:
This time I considered only half the circuit:

[image] [image]

If both \$D_1\$ and \$D_2\$ are off, then I can say that \$V_{A1} = V_{A2} = V_s(t) = 0V\$, \$V_{K1} = \frac{\left( R/4 + R/4 \right)}{\left( R/4 + R/4 \right) + R/4}9V = \frac{2}{3}9V = 6V\$ and \$V_{K2} = \frac{R/4}{R/4 + R/4 + R/4}9V = \frac{1}{3}9V = 3V\$.

Therefore, until \$V_s(t)\$ doesn't reach \$3V\$, \$V_o(t) = V_s(t)\$.

When \$V_s(t) = 3V\$, \$D_2\$ is forward biased and the circuit becomes:

[image]

Applying Millman two times I can derive \$V_o(t)\$:

First I simplified the branch like so: \$\frac{\frac{9V}{\frac{R}{4}+\frac{R}{4}}}{\frac{4}{R}+\frac{1}{\frac{4}{R}+\frac{4}{R}}} = \frac{2}{6}9V = 3V\$.

And then derived \$V_o(t) = \frac{4V_s(t)+3\left(3V\right)}{4+3} = \frac{4}{7}V_s(t)+\frac{9}{7}V\$.

My problem lies here: I know that the value of \$V_{K1}\$ has changed but I don't know how to calculate it..

If I'd be able to, I could say for what value of \$V_o(t)\$ \$D_1\$ would get forward biased and the circuit would become:

[image]

And therefore \$V_o(t) = \frac{4\frac{V_s(t)}{R}+4\frac{9V}{R}}{\frac{4}{R}+\frac{4}{R}+\frac{28}{11R}} = \frac{11}{29}V_s(t)+\frac{11}{29}9V\$.

But now I wouldn't know how to justify that the other half of the circuit is the opposite of the one I just analyzed..

Comment: The post is very big, which is good on the description coefficient, but bad on the reading coefficient. You need to describe the formula, which transforms the square wave to a sin wave, including the diodes. That means Square volts multiplied by and etc. to reach a sin wave.

Comment: @CFCBazar I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: CFC - The title is pretty clear, the input is a triangle wave.